# testear eventos durante ejecucion de escena

Tags: c#, unity3d, eventos

tengo dos scripts:

life: asignado a un gameobject Player

StatusController: asignado a un panel en el que tengo dos image, uno para vida y otro para mana

el script life tiene un event y su delegado, para que cuando la "vida" del personaje cambia (cuando se ejecuta Damage), lance el evento ChangeLife. Además, la propiedad **live** es publica (para manejarla desde el editor en tiempo de ejecucion y ver sus valores):

```
public class Life : MonoBehaviour {
    [SerializeField] float MaxLive;
    public float live;

    public delegate void ChangeLive(float value);
    public  event ChangeLive LiveChange;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
    }

    public void Damage(float damage) {
        live = Mathf.Clamp(live - damage, 0, MaxLive);
        var handler = LiveChange;
        if (handler != null) {
            handler(live);
        }
        if (live <= 0) {
            Deadfx();
        }
    }
```

StatusController Se conecta al evento LiveChange en el start (recojo player con un GameManager):

```
public class GUIStatusController : MonoBehaviour {
    [SerializeField] Image imgLife, imgMana;
    GameObject player;

    void Start () {
        player = GameManager.instance.player;

        player.GetComponent<Life>().LiveChange += ChangeLife;
    }

    void ChangeLife(float value)
    {
        imgLife.fillAmount = value;
    }
```

El problema que tengo es que, cuando ejecuto el juego, No se actualiza la imagen de Life. Asi que para testearlo, cuando estoy en ejecucion del editor, cambio el valor de la propiedad. PERO (y aqui esta la cosa) no veo cambios en ningun sitio.
He pensado que (quizas) desde el editor en tiempo de ejecucion, el cambiar valores de una propiedad NO LANZA eventos. Si esto es asi, no puedo testear esta parte del juego.

Existe alguna manera de lanzar eventos en tiempo de ejecucion desde el editor, para ver si esta propiedad (y lo que quiero hacer) cambia?

Answer (score 0):

Podrías ir usando *`Debug.Log(“nombreEvento”);`* justo en el lugar donde tienes el evento que quieres ver si funciona. Espero que te sirva, y que sea eso lo que necesitas. Esta es solo la la manera mas simple que hay para hacerlo.

Un ejemplo:

```
public void Accion1(){
//Tu acción 
*Debug.Log(“Nombre de acción “)* 
  }
```

En el lugar de *Debug.Log();* puedes agregar algun int, en este caso el de la vida, el cual quedaría `Debug.Log(“Vida : “ + VidaInt`);

Comment: Bienvenido Juan explica mas tu respuesta para que sea mejor recibida

Comment: gracias Juan Vial. El asunto es precisamente que aunque pongo esos Debug.log en las acciones, no llegan a ejecutarse al momento de cambiar las propiedades del objeto. Yo supongo que es porque no se lanzan los eventos cuando se cambia desde el editor.

Comment: Voy a mirar en el pc para ver en que te puedo ayudar

Comment: Al cambiar el valor desde el editor, presionas enter? Me surgió esta duda ya que en mas de una ocasión que me a ocurrido se a actualizado el valor, ejecutare el código yo ahora mismo y si no es eso te aviso! Saludos.